# HttpWebRequest with Method Post

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I have this link: http://www2.correios.com.br/sistemas/rastreamento/

and need fill textarea and do subit button buscar, for that Im using this code:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www2.correios.com.br/sistemas/rastreamento/ctrl/ctrlRastreamento.cfm");
        request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        request.Method = "POST";
        string postData = "objetos=PU633524761BR";
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        dataStream.Close();




        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
        textBox.Text = responseFromServer;
        dataStream.Close();
```

why dont return tracking history?
for track you can you this track number: LB250377577SE

Comment: I think the issue is that you use `http` instead of `https` in the url

Comment: omg, solve the problem, thank you very much